# show that $(\forall (a,b)\in R^{+2}) ( \frac{a}{1+b}=\frac{b}{1+a}\implies a=b ) $

Tags: contest-math, real-numbers

$$ \left(\forall (a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^{+2}\right)  \left( \dfrac{a}{1+b}=\dfrac{b}{1+a}\implies a=b \right) $$

My attempts:
let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

$$\dfrac{a}{1+b}=\dfrac{b}{1+a}\implies a\left(1+a \right)=b\left( 1+b\right)\implies a+a^2=b+b^2 \implies a-b=b^2-a^2 \implies a-b=-(a-b)(a+b) $$

I'm looking also for other ways to solve that questions

Comment: If $a\neq b$ then $a-b = -(a-b)(a+b)\Rightarrow a+b = -1$, but $a,b>0$...

Comment: $\implies a+b=-1$…

Answer (score 2):

You are almost done. You already proved that $\dfrac{a}{1+b}=\dfrac{b}{1+a}$ implies 
$$
 a-b = -(a-b)(a+b) \, .
$$
Now write that as
$$
  (a-b)(1+a+b) = 0
$$
and note that $1+a+b > 0$ since both $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be *positive.*

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=x(1+x)$, $x >0$, is a strictly increasing function, injective.

$f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}a^2+a &=& b^2+b\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;/\cdot 4\;\;\;\; /+1\\
&\implies & 4a^2+4a+1 =4b^2+4b+1\\
&\implies &(2a+1)^2= (2b+1)^2\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;/ \surd\\
&\implies &|2a+1|=|2b+1|\end{eqnarray}

Since $a,b$ are positive we have now $$2a+1= 2b+1\implies a=b$$